# How can I change tables referent to another database?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I'm using **SQL Server 2008** and I have 2 databases, it's **`DB01`** and **`DB02`**.
I'm moving tables **`[MY_TABLE]`** from **`DB01`** to **`DB02`** and remove each tables from **`DB01`**.
But in **`DB01`** I have 150 stored procedures, 50 functions and 50 views that use those tables.

> It take a lot of time if I change **`[DB01].[dbo].[ME_TABLE]`** to
>   **`[DB02].[dbo].[ME_TABLE]`** one by one.

How can i achieve this by other me methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can script those stored procedure from **DB001** and execute them on **DB002** where you want to use them. You can delete them later from **DB001** if you want to, will save you time.

Comment: But in those stored procedure have it own tables.

Comment: It have only one tables.

Comment: Do you want to use procedures from **DB001** in **DB002**. Or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Such as my stored procedure have [DB01].[db0].[MY_TABLE] and [DB01].[db0].[MY_TABLE02]. Then I move [MY_TABLE] to DB02, I must edit [DB01].[db0].[MY_TABLE] to [DB02].[db0].[MY_TABLE] but it take a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point. You can script them into your new database as suggested. You don't have to go on renaming everything.

Comment: Then what can i do with [DB01].[db0].[MY_TABLE02] in that stored procedure.

Comment: What do you have to do with [DB01].[db0].[MY_TABLE02], when you'll have [DB02].[db0].[MY_TABLE02] in your new DB.

Comment: I have only [MY_TABLE] in DB02

Answer (score 0):

> Paste the query in new database.Problem Solved !

[image]

Comment: My problem not how to move table. But it is what the best solution to change table referent in stored procedure, function and view.

Comment: you may have to change and replace table names from query window

Comment: Yes I want to do in query window